# In Notepad ++: Replacing some string with something else in all the lines containing another string

Tags: replace, notepad++

In the example below, is there any way to place a string like ("1one1") before {",} at the end of all lines which contain {ī}?

īn:"ZZin",
ín:"FFin",
ǐn:"QQin",
ìn:"TTin",
ie:"XXie",
iē:"TTie",
ié:"GGie",

Thanks

Comment: you want to add these characteres or replace the current string between "" ? for example: replace īn:"ZZin" to īn:"ZZin1one1" or replace īn:"ZZin" to īn:"1one1" ?

Comment: in this example, yes, "ZZin" must be replaced with "ZZin", but I have many lines (more than 8000) and only a few of them has "ZZin", while there are a lot more which has "ī" and I want to change {",} at the end of those lines to {1one1",}.

Comment: i understand that can be any string inside the "", i need to know if you want do complete de string with "1one1", and than it will be "string1one1" or replace it at all and then it will be only "1one1".

Comment: My head is spinning 0_o

Comment: @tfidelis yeah, i want to keep everything in the line but {",} like "string1one1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++ regex search for `^(.*ī.*)(",)$` and replace with `\11one1\2`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use regex [regex for notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

so, mark "Regular Expression" in the final of Replace box.

in your fields to search:

`find what:`       ī.[^"]"([A-Za-z0-9]*)

`replace with:`    īn:"\11one1

i think it will do what you want. Let me know if it doesn't to edit the regex.

Comment: Another regex since you beat me to it: `^(.*ī.*)(",)$` replaced with `\11one1\2`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `ī.[^"]"([A-Za-z0-9]*)` correctly select the lines. but not all of the lines which `ī` starts with `īn`. i think what is needed is a code to select `",` in the lines which has `ī` (and not the line itself), and then to replace only the selected part not the whole line.

Comment: @Alden Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alden Please write your comment as an Answer, so that I can verify the answer for other fellows.

Comment: @EsRa I'm glad it worked. I have submitted an answer.